# Como fazer um INNER JOIN trazendo campos específicos de duas tabelas e retirando os registros repetidos e com uma condição de max?

Tags: mysql, query, phpmyadmin

Bom, tenho as seguintes tabelas:

Tabela 01:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E tabela 02:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí gostaria de trazer somente todos os campos com maior pontos e que não repita o garçom no caso, como fazer?

Comment: Os nomes que aparecem na tabela 01 são os nomes dos garçons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Somando** os Pontos do mesmo garçom (ex.: Juliana Oliveira => 100 + 123)

```
SELECT g.nome Garcom,sum(p.pontos) TotalPontos
FROM tabela01 g
JOIN tabela02 p ON p.garcom_id = g.id
GROUP BY g.nome 
ORDER BY sum(p.pontos) DESC,g.nome
```

**Sem somar**, pegando o maior ponto de cada garçom

```
SELECT g.nome Garcom,max(p.pontos) maior
FROM tabela01 g
JOIN tabela02 p ON p.garcom_id = g.id
GROUP BY g.nome 
ORDER BY max(p.pontos) DESC,g.nome
```

P.S.: Altere o `tabela01` e `tabela02` para o nome das respectivas tabelas

Se quiser os primeiros registros filtre pelos primeiros N registros que voce deseja e você não informou que tipo de banco de dados é.

SqlServer seria adicionar um TOP N logo após o select (`SELECT TOP 10 ....`);

PostgreSql seria adicionar um LIMIT N no final (`ORDER BY ..... LIMIT 10`);

Oracle é beemmm mais complicado, nem vou postar aqui, vou informar um link (achei no google) [Oracle](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/top-n-queries)

MySql é igual PostgreSql, usa LIMIT no final

Comment: MySQL é o banco, quero a maior pontuação... Ex.: pedro, 110pts, joao, 98pts, pedro, 115pts... Logo a query traz: pedro 110pst... joao 115pts. Entendeu?

Comment: vc quer somar os pontos do mesmo garçom ou nao? ex.: Juliana Oliveira -> 100 e 123

Comment: Adicionei `DESC` ao SQL para ordem descendente (estava faltando isso)

Comment: Nao quero soma, so quero trazer o registro com a maior pontuação, caso exista outro garçom com as mesmas características traga o com a maior pontuação, isso para todos os registros!

Comment: Acho que resolvi... Valeu!